# How do i fade in and out a color change for a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS and javascript to fade in and out different colours for a div using multiple buttons and I got the code to work in codepen but when I tried to use it on the website it didn't work and I'm not sure why, the code is as follows:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var valColor = $(this).val();

  $('.change').css({
    background: valColor
  });
});
```

```css
.change {
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: .6s ease;
  -o-transition: .6s ease;
  background-color: rgb(25, 65, 196);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(25, 65, 196);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="change">
</div>
</br>
<button value="rgb(31, 221, 97)" class="black btn">On</button>
<button value="rgb(221, 56, 30)" class="red btn">Off</button>
```

like I said it worked in codepen but when I exported it and tried to use it in an HTML document it didn't work, I have no idea what the issue is so sorry if it is obvious.

Comment: Its look like you forgot Jquery script :`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Add Jquery script to your project in the `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is learn about Jquery:https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
   var valColor = $(this).val();

   $('.change').css({
       background: valColor        
   });
});
```

```css
.change{
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease;
  -moz-transition: .6s ease;
  -ms-transition: .6s ease;
  -o-transition: .6s ease;
  background-color:rgb(25, 65, 196);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(25, 65, 196);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
</div>
</br>
<button value="rgb(31, 221, 97)" class="black btn">On</button>
<button value="rgb(221, 56, 30)" class="red btn">Off</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned you have to add jquery to your script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that you might want to add the transition field without prefix and specifiy the color explicitly:

```
transition: background-color .6s ease;
```